# Creating Vuex getters dynamically from database data

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm trying to dynamically create Vuex getters based on database data.

There are two columns within the database table that are of importance. One column is the getter name, and the second is the getters contents. The state values that the getters will be referencing will already be loaded into the store when it's created, so that won't be an issue.

I've read up on creating modules and registering them, but in all cases I've seen they still have to be hardcoded. Is there anyway of making this work?

I'm also considering whether it would be better to store getters and their associated state values within Vuex modules as a string in the database, to then pull them out and register them.

What approach would you take?

Thanks in advance.

Joe

Comment: Vuex getters are for computing value based off the store. I wouldn't use them to just access state data. You can just access the state itself for that.

Comment: Thanks for replying James. I would be performing calculations within these getters. You're absolutely right though and that's the approach I would take when I only need to return state data.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is in a similar situation, I ended up importing an empty vuex module and caching it to a variable, assigning new getter functions and then registering it, similar to this:

```
import emptyVuexModule from 'emptyModule'

let cachedModule = emptyVuexModule

cachedModule.getters[getterName] = new Function(['state'], getterContents)

this.$store.registerModule(cachedModule)
```

I don't know if this is the best solution and I know using new Function comes with security issues, but it works for my needs.